# Parsing text from HTML formatted email

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, html-parsing

I get inbound emails with the html formatting below (Probably copy/pasted from office and sent with outlook) This causes formatting issues when my HTML enabled UI is displaying the email content.So to resolve it I copy the HTML content to an online HTML editor or I save it as html file and run it in browser so I can copy the text only to get rid of the garbage html and styling tags. I dont have the option of using Frames in my markup to suppress the HTML and CSS and prevent it from affecting the page styling.

Is there any other way that I can resolve this issue pragmatically and parse the text out every time I detect the 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' in the body of inbound emails?

I also went as far as writing a code that removes tags (e.g. anything between `<head>` and `</head>`) but I would like to see if anyone can offer a more efficient way of handling this or an alternate to Frames to suppress the bad HTML in the email body content on my UI

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
 {font-family:Wingdings;
 panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
 {font-family:PMingLiU;
 panose-1:2 2 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"Cambria Math";
 panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"\@PMingLiU";
 panose-1:2 2 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"Berlin Sans FB";
 panose-1:2 14 6 2 2 5 2 2 3 6;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
 {margin:0in;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:#0563C1;
 text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:#954F72;
 text-decoration:underline;}
p
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
 margin-right:0in;
 mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
 margin-left:0in;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
span.EmailStyle18
 {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
 {mso-style-type:export-only;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
 {size:8.5in 11.0in;
 margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
 {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">See below.&nbsp; 
</span><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:Wingdings;color:#1F497D">J</span><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#C45911">PLEASE NOTE THE FOLLOWING:
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#C45911">M<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#C45911"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#C45911">
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Berlin Sans FB&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Berlin Sans FB&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">Thank you!<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Berlin Sans FB&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p></o:p></span></p>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Chilkat's HTMLToText method and it's brilliant.

Thanks